# BCNF -- Impossible to achieve?

Tags: database, database-normalization

Let R be a relation with Schema R(X,Y,Z)
and it's FDs are
**{XY -> Z,  Z -> Y}**
I am not able to decompose it into **BCNF** .
 Because **r1(Z,Y)**,  **r2(Z,X)** will lose FD **XY -> Z** and
       R(X,Y,Z) itself is not the solution as  **Z->Y** shows that Z should be a key ..

How to do this ???

Comment: I think its not possible in this case ...BCNF is not always achievable ..

Comment: It's always possible to achieve BCNF with respect to a set of dependencies but a BCNF schema isn't necessarily *dependency-preserving*. Some dependencies may be lost. This is one such case.

Comment: Beeri and Bernstein showed that, unlike the first three normal forms, BCNF is not always achievable. Google it.

Comment: for example, a set of functional dependencies {AB → C, C → B}

Comment: Beeri and Bernstein demonstrated that the problem of finding BCNF for a given set of dependencies was NP-Complete, not that it was ever "unachievable". It is always achievable if you accept that some dependencies aren't preserved. Proof: Any schema can be decomposed into a a 6NF schema (by decomposition into keys + at-most one nonprime attribute). Any 6NF schema also satisfies BCNF.

Comment: The example question posed here (and by TJ as well) is one used by Zaniolo in his 1982 paper on EKNF. The BCNF solution is R1{A,B},R2{C,B}.

Answer (score 1):

Every conversion into BCNF may not be dependency preserving

We only need to give a counter example:
 Consider the following schema;

a b c and c->b
Clearly the above schema is in 3NF, 
because ab->c is a superkey dependency and ,from c->b we
can see that b-c=b, which is a subset of the primary key (such dependency is also allowed in 3NF).
But, the above schema is not in BCNF because c->b is neither super-key nor trivial dependency.
So we decompose above schema , keeping it lossless.
Only possible lossless decomposition is: ac and cb. (because,their intersection c is primary key for the 2nd table).
But clearly the dependency ab->c is lost.
Hence, proved.